# How do I match a filter to an AWGN channel?

Tags: filters, nyquist, matched-filter, cosine

I have the task to find a transition that fulfills the first Nyquist Criterion. After that I am supposed to match that filter to an AWGN channel. For the first part I thought a raised cosine transition in the frequency domain should be a good start. But now, I don’t know how to match that filter to an AWGN channel in the frequency domain. I only know matched filtering in the time domain. Does someone know what I have to do? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why are you using a raised cosine filter in the frequency domain? A matched filter is a system that convolutes the signal input signal with a time-inversed replicate of the transmitted signal, in the case of the radar, or the non-modulated transmitted signal in the case of a communications system. By knowing that a convolution in time is a multiplication in frequency you'll be able to perform the matched filter.

Comment: small problem: "matching a filter to …" takes another filter, or at least convolutional system, like @DaDSPGuy says. Now, you want to "match a filter to an AWGN channel". Um, that AWGN channel, that's not much of a filter, so how would you match that? In time domain, an AWGN channel is identity (representable by convolution with a Dirac Delta), and addition of noise.

Comment: One doesn't match a filter to a _channel_; one matches a filter to a _received signal_. The received signal includes the effect of the channel on the _transmitted_ signal, and since the only effect that an AWGN channel has on a signal is that noise gets added to whatever was transmitted, one needs to just match to the transmitted signal -- the received signal is exactly the same as the transmitted signal. For more complicated channels that introduce intersymbol interference and/or add colored (instead of white) Gaussian noise to the transmitted signal, the matched filters are more complicated,

Comment: @DaDSPGuy I believe the description "a raised cosine transition in the frequency domain" is accurate for a raised cosine filter: The frequency response has a transition described by $(1+cos())/2$. Time domain filtering (convolution)  as done  in the frequency domain is a product of the frequency domain signal with that raised cosine shape. The raised cosine in frequency is the windowed Sinc function in the time domain we recognize for an RC filter. (That's an aside but wanted to clear up that part of the confusion).

Comment: @DaDSPGuy I was using a raised cosine, so that no intersymbol interferrence would occur. As I understand you I would need some kind of Information of the transmitted signal in order to perform the task?

Comment: @MarcusMüller So you are saying the task does not make much sense? I was also very confused by it honostly. Or do I understand something wrong?

Comment: @DilipSarwate So you are also saying, that the task does not make much sense? Or if I may ask, how would you match a transmit filter in a AWGN channal to an arbitrary transmitted signal?

Comment: Could you state the "task" that you have been "assigned" in the _exact_ words  used by the assignor instead of filtering the assignment through your own understanding of what is being asked? Your newest query in the comment above makes even less sense than the ones in the original question.

Comment: The original take read as follows "Sketch an arbitrary transition that fulfills the first Nyquist criterion" Then the second task is "The filter shall now be matched to an AWGN channel. Sketch the transmit filter in the same figure that you used for the overall filter."